# Duplicate dynamic select boxes using clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2, clone

I have a `div` in my code which I need to duplicate as the user clicks on the `Add` button. In the div there are 2 dropdowns one which is populated dynamically from database and the other one dynamically populated based on the first dropdown selection.

I have achieved duplicating the `div` using jQuery [clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). But the dynamically populating feature isn't working for the first dropdown divs so as the  second one. Also, sometimes when I select an option in parent div, that's also showing weird selections.

```js
var count = 1;
$('#add-new').click(function() {
  //clone
  var row = $('#scope-brand-div').clone(true);
  row.appendTo('#clone-parent');
  //add new ids
  var scopeselect = $('select.scope-select');
  var brandselect = $('select.brand-select');
  $(row).find(scopeselect).attr('id', 'project-scope' + count);
  $(row).find(brandselect).attr('id', 'brands_used' + count);
  count++;
});
```

```html
<form action="add_project" method="POST">
  <h4>Project Scope&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="clone" name="addnew" id="add-new">Add</button></h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row" id="clone-parent">
        <div id="scope-brand-div">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="scope"><?php echo $this->lang->line('xin_project_scope');?></label>
              <select name="scope" class="form-control select-border-color border-warning scope-select" data-plugin="select_hrm" data-placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('xin_project_scope');?>" id="project-scope">
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach($all_project_scope as $scope) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $scope->scope_id; ?>">
                  <?php echo $scope->scope_name; ?>
                </option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group" id="brands-ajax">
              <label for="brands_used"><?php echo $this->lang->line('xin_brands_used');?></label>
              <select name="brands_used" id="brands_used" class="form-control select-border-color border-warning brand-select" data-plugin="select_hrm" data-placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('xin_brands_used');?>">
                <option value=""></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit name=" submit " id="submit-form " value="Submit ">
</form>
```

Comment: The issue is because the `#add-new` button is missing a `type` attribute, so it's considered to be a `submit` button. As such it's submitting the form as soon as you click it. All you need to do it set `type="button"` on the element to fix this issue.

Comment: That isn't the issue. I had checked it before.

Comment: Yes, it is the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/tckfb2x5/

Comment: Also note that your attempt to update the `id` attribute of the row is flawed. You shouldn't really be creating/amending `id` at runtime anyway - use classes

Comment: I tried adding the `type` attribute, but it isn't changing the result. As you mentioned I have used classes.